# Working DNS-DHCP combo for LAN

Tags: dhcp, dns

Can anyone recommend a working DNS-DHCP combo for a small mixed-platform LAN?  Preferably one where hosts can be assigned IP addresses and/or names with a web-GUI.  The typical DHCP package on Linux claims to support BIND, but last I checked, it did not actually work.  Of course, this might be out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a small network I would use `dnsmasq`.  It performs well for both DNS and DHCP.   It does self registration internally, so the client does not need to register.  This is more secure.  There are configuration options to specify another server should be consulted for a domain.  It will serve static address via DHCP either via configuration or `/etc/ethers`. Local static names are loaded from `/etc/hosts` and/or any other file you configure.

I haven't examined any of the other DHCP servers to see if they support registering with bind.

It has been my experience the that the DHCP client packages on Linux do support BIND.  However, it registering with the name server is often not enabled by default.  Linux has a history of being used more as a sever where the IP address will be static (even if served by DHCP).  Linux desktops are becoming more frequent, and if I were rolling them out in a corporate environment I might enable registration.

Enabling DHCP registration in bind risks DNS hijacking.  It is best to use a separate domain for dynamic addresses.  To use client registration, it must be enabled in the bind configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The [ISC suite](http://www.isc.org/software) works, if a bit complicated to set up. No GUI though. The [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) server also works well for smaller installations with another authoritative name server. It is one binary so automatic name entries are easy.